# how to build a dropdownlistfor in asp mvc4 from a db inside a partial view

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, dropdownlistfor

while ive build mvc projects i havent done them in asp.net mvc4.5
so pls forgive me if this question seems really obvious to answer
or if im making obvious noob mistakes
pls feel free to correct all issues...

ive actually been googling all weekend and i seem to get bits of answers
but havent been able to pull it all together

so as the title says im trying to build a simple dropdownlistfor 
where the data is pulled from the db 
to add another layer of complexity
this DDLF is in a partial view

so heres what ive got

model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace proj.Models
{
public class chartType
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string typename { get; set; }
}

public class chartTypeVM
{
    [Display(Name = "selectedID")]
    public int selectedChartType { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List { get; set; }
}
}
```

controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using proj.Models;

namespace proj.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    orojDB db = new orojDB ();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        chartTypeVM model = initialiseSM();            

        return View(model);
    }

    private chartTypeVM initialiseSM()
    {

        // make scenario DDL
        // using chartTypes for now
        var q = db.chartTypes
            .Select(ct=> new {
                ct.id,
                ct.typename
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(ct => new SelectListItem {
                Value = ct.id.ToString(),
                Text = ct.typename
            });

        var cts = new chartTypeVM{
            List = q.AsEnumerable()
        };
        cts.selectedChartType = 1;

        Debug.WriteLine("asdfasdf");

        return cts;
    }
}
}
```

view:

```
@using proj.Models
@model chartTypeVM

<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>

@* *************** sections *************** *@
@section sm {
        <div id="sm">
            <section class="content-wrapper sm-content">
                @Html.Partial("_smPartial", Model)
            </section>
            <div class="smCloseD"><img src="/Images/closeArrow.png" alt="Open Scenario Manager" /></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
}
```

main layout (most of it not shown) :

```
@using proj.Models
@model chartTypeVM

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>

        @RenderSection("sm",false);
```

and finally the partial:

```
@using proj.Models

@model chartTypeVM
<section class="smVars">
<div class="varLabel">Scenario:</div>
<div class="varInput">@Html.DropDownListFor( model=>model.selectedChartType, (SelectList)model.List)</div>
</section>
```

with the things ive tried
i getting errs like:
- The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
- or the one about not being able to use dynamic variables
- or something being inferred

anyways if you could help id be very grateful
=:-)
thanks!

Comment: note: this code is being adjusted as i am working thru the prob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `DropDownListFor` helper your view needs to be strongly typed to a model. In your case that would be the `chartTypeVM` class. So add a `@model` directive to the top of your partial view indicating the view model being used:

```
@model chartTypeVM
<section class="smVars">
    <div class="varLabel">Scenario:</div>
    <div class="varInput">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedChartType, (SelectList)Model.List)
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: hi darin!  first of all lemme say thanks  
and actually this example has been pulled together because of all your helpful comments on other posts  
so really ... thanks!  
ok - back to the problem  
ive edited the orig code to add your suggs  
and in fact ive also adjusted the capitalisation of "model" 
AND i had to add the namespace (why??) 
finally this is what i got - 
    The name 'model' does not exist in the current context.
for the line 
    @Html.Partial("_smPartial", model).

so i added the namespace and model here (again y here?)
and still got the same err. thanks agn for yr insight

Comment: Replace `@Html.Partial("_smPartial", model)` with `@Html.Partial("_smPartial", Model)` and also make sure that your main view is strongly typed to the same model using the `@model` directive at the top of your view as shown in my answer.

Comment: hey darin! thanks for your reply!  so as you can see from the code i made the adjustments you sugg
and i even included the directive in the main layout page 
now when i run it with this:

@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.selectedChartType, (SelectList)model.List)

i get this err: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

n when i run this:
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model=>Model.selectedChartType, (SelectList)Model.List)
i get this:
CS0136: A local variable named 'Model' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'Model',

Comment: You should pay more attention to casing. Look at my answer: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedChartType, (SelectList)Model.List)`. Now look at your code: `@Html.DropDownListFor( model=>model.selectedChartType, (SelectList)model.List)`. See the difference? `Model.List` is not the same as `model.List`. C# is a case sensitive language. Also you should not use `Model` as variable name. When your view is strongly typed to some model (`@model ...`) you should use the `Model` keyword to reference the instance of this model and not attempt to override it.

Comment: hey darin- look im trying my best here.  if you look at my code in the question which ive been updating, youll see its been adjusted and in fact i tried several combinations which is what i was trying to explain to you in my previous comment.  i didnt understand the diff between 'model' and 'Model' other than obviously they were diff vars which was part of my question - which you just answered so thanks for that =:-)  anywyas 'model' is still giving me a non-existent context err even with all the declared namespaces!!  any other suggs?

Comment: If you get an error that `model` doesn't exist then you forgot to add a `@model ...` at the top of your view or you are trying to use the `model` variable outside of a lambda expression which is incorrect. If you get an error stating that a local variable named `'Model'` cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to `'Model'` then you probably declared a `Model` variable somewhere in your Razor view which once again is incorrect.

Comment: ok i will try it again
but i have added both `@using` and `@model` to every layout and view files
thanks darin!